How to used SharedArrayBuffer in iframe without iframe unsandboxing itself
I want to allow a sandboxed iframe to use SharedArrayBuffer with web workers created by the iframe. To use SharedArrayBuffer I have to set the following headers
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp

However, if I set those headers then the iframe refuses to load and chrome throws a warning stating

An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can escape its sandboxing.

How can I allow the iframe to use SharedArrayBuffer without allowing the iframe to unsandbox itself?
The answer here SharedArrayBuffer in an Iframe suggests

adding allow-scripts and allow-same-origin tokens in the iframe's sandbox attribute

but that's exactly what chrome is telling me not to do.
Also I have control over the top level webpage and iframe's server, but the iframe is a sandbox that runs user provided code so I must assume that it will run malicious code which is why it's important that it can't unsandbox itself as the top level domain contains sensitive information such as the user's authentication token.
If it matters in the sandbox iframe I have  Content-Security-Policy set to default-src data: blob: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.kastatic.org *.kasandbox.or cdn.jsdelivr.net;


I've received the warning

An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can escape its sandboxing.

on Google Chrome when I use following Content-Security-Policy fragment of the host document:
Content-Security-Policy: ... sandbox allow-downloads allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-presentation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation;
And I don't even need to use and <iframe> element to get the warning to JS console! As such, I think there's something broken in the test that emits this warning.
The intent is to allow <iframe> elements in user generated content loaded from different origin into the iframe but newer allow allow-top-navigation. Obviously we don't want content in <iframe> to be allow to lift these restrictions so if you cannot modify host document HTTP headers, you cannot break this – assuming there are no security vulnerabilities in the browser itself.

It's good information to know that Chromium is probably broken, but I don't think you've answered my question because it doesn't tell me how to get Chromium to stop refusing the load the iframe and let the iframe use SharedArrayBuffer.

Does the host document set HTTP header Content-Security-Protection? If it does, you should update the question to declare its value or we cannot know why the iframe fails.

I don't think Content-Security-Protection is a standard header. I do have Content-Security-Policy set to default-src data: blob: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.kastatic.org *.kasandbox.or cdn.jsdelivr.net;

Yeah, I meant Content-Security-Policy. I would suggest trying adding sandbox allow-scripts allow-same-origin to host document HTTP headers if possible. Chrome will show a warning in JS console but if you get your code to work, you can be sure that the failure is caused by browser implemented security restrictions.
